# Riemannian Triangles Third Side

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, triangles

Suppose I have a Geodesically complete Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with bounded curvature.  Let $A,B,C$ be points on the $M$ and let $E_A^B,E_B^C,E_C^A$ be geodesic segments connecting $A,B,C$ respectively.

If I know the length of $E_A^B$ and of $E_B^C$ then can I explicitly compute $E_C^A$?

Comment: what do you mean by explicitly? which kinds of dependencies are allowed and which are forbidden?

Comment: Is there a general closed-form formula or closed-form upper bound (finite :P )

Comment: There is certainly no closed-form formula. If you are requiring the segments to be minimizing then $|E_A^B| +| E_B^C|$ is obviously an upper bound; and you can't really expect to do better than this without extra information. (That is, unless your "bounded curvature" includes a positive lower bound, in which case Myer's theorem could help.)

Comment: No its a negative lower bound and the upper bound is 0.